# how to locate a partucular letter in a word in sybase(like we do instr in SQL)

Tags: sybase-ase15

I am working in Sybase environment and trying to figure out how to find the records that have particular letter in a word from a column

example i have a column name plan name it has records like 'MYMR001','SYMR0101',NYMR1111' ETC..  i need to locate the 'R'  in the 4th digit of the plan name column and fetch those records. i am new to Sybase trying to get the correct syntax , can  any one here help me out!!!

i tried the below syntax:
select TOP 1 sub string('plan name',char index("R", "NYMR0000")+1,4) FROM  table

Answer (score 0):

To *find* something you need to place a test in the `where` clause, eg:

```
select *
from   <table>
where  substring([plan name],4,1) = 'R'
```